# Higher priority of dialogues window than DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a strange problem with displaying elements on page in a good order. I want to show at the begining `document.write` with welcome, then ask for a name with `prompt` and at the end show the result on the page. Somehow before anything shows a prompt is displaying. Why is this happening? This is for a school purpose :)

```js
document.write(`Hello `);
const text = prompt(`what's your name?`);
document.write(`${text}, nice to meet you :)`);
```

If something is unclear, feel free to ask :)

Comment: A prompt is displaying after "Hello" is written, what is not working as you expect?

Comment: Beware of "Hello null, nice to meet you"

Comment: @php_nub_qq only when you use mozilla as your browser, try again but in chrome :)

Comment: You are not going to get that because how the browser renders content. And soon you will learn that document.write is a bad solution.

Comment: As I said it is only for a school purpose, we're doing excercies and we wonder if we're able to do that somehow

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, this works differently in different browsers and I suspect that is due to how browsers go about their rendering cycles.

It goes beyond `document.write`, if you try to append an element to the document you will observe the exact same behavior.

I tried to force chrome to render in-between the `write/append` calls but it sturdily refused to. I'm guessing this is some kind of supposed optimization on their side, not sure, but if you really insist on doing that you'll have to employ an additional context, and that will not work with `document.write` as it will overwrite whatever is already in the document.